# How can I get the actual byte count for all malloc'ed bytes in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, memory-management

Like the Allocations profiler, I want to get the current 'live bytes' at runtime.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with using Instruments? Is there something you'd actually do based on memory allocated (rather than, say, memory free)? Given how the OS manages memory, it's hard to come up with anything that a typical app would be able to do with this knowledge.

Comment: I want something I can inspect during development in the UI (when I am not tethered).  I want to be able to log this value periodically to a log.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try.  One is to use the `malloc_zone_statistics` function.  You'll need to have a look at `malloc/malloc.h` since there's no man page.

```
#import <malloc/malloc.h>

static void dumpMallocStats() {
    malloc_statistics_t stats;
    malloc_zone_statistics(NULL, &stats);
    NSLog(@"size_allocated = %lu", (unsigned long)stats.size_allocated);
}
```